# ios camera perform action when shutter button pressed

Tags: ios

In my app i want to know what time it is precisely when the shutter button is pressed on the camera view. For that i have a function that gets the time from atomic clocks exactly when it's called. I would like to attach that function to be called instantly when the shutter button is pressed.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the PhotoPicker class has been implemented. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196
Copy-paste the code and add/modify it the way you want it